# How to work out mean after specific number of months for different customers using python?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a `dataframe` of customers and how much they spend each month as shown below:

```
data =[['Armin',12,5,11,24,5,4,10,5],['Benji',10,12,10,32,4,18,0,0],['Casey',0,0,30,15,25,5,0,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','2019-01','2019-02','2019-03','2019-04','2019-05','2019-06','2019-07','2019-08'])
```

I need to work out the 3 month average for each customer starting from their specified month as shown by the dataframe below:

```
data2 = [['Armin','2019-04'],['Benji','2019-02'],['Casey','2019-03']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['Name','Specified Month'])
```

So for Armin the 3-month average starting from his specified month would be `(24 + 5 + 4)/3 = 11`.

The expected result would be something similar to below:

```
df['Specified Average'] = [11,18,23.3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get positions by [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) in `df`, then select next 3 values with `np.add.outer` and get `mean`:

```
N = 3
a = df.columns.get_indexer(df2['Specified Month'])

df2['Specified Average'] = (np.mean(df.values[np.arange(len(df)), 
                                             np.add.outer(np.arange(N), a)], axis=0)
                              .astype(float))
print (df2)
    Name Specified Month  Specified Average
0  Armin         2019-04          11.000000
1  Benji         2019-02          18.000000
2  Casey         2019-03          23.333333
```

Another pandas only solution is more general - working if data not exist between both DataFrames and also working if next 3 months not exist for any datetime:

```
s = (df.reset_index()
       .melt(id_vars=['Name','index'], var_name='Specified Month')
       .merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)
       .assign(groups=lambda x: x['_merge'].eq('both').astype(int).groupby(x['Name']).cumsum())
       .query("groups != 0")
       .groupby('Name')
       .head(N)
       .sort_values('index')
       .groupby('Name', sort=False)['value']
       .mean()
         )

print (s)
Name
Armin    11.000000
Benji    18.000000
Casey    23.333333
Name: value, dtype: float64

df2['Specified Average'] = s.values
print (df2)
    Name Specified Month  Specified Average
0  Armin         2019-04          11.000000
1  Benji         2019-02          18.000000
2  Casey         2019-03          23.333333
```